# Создать функцию «arange», которая дублирует «xrange» в Python2, но может обрабатывать числовой тип <long>

Tags: python, python-2.x

Можно ли как-то упростить код?  Каким еще способом можно это реализовать?

Создать функцию «arange», которая дублирует «xrange» в Python2, но может обрабатывать числовой тип `<long>`.
Он должен поддерживать позиционные аргументы, отрицательные числа для любого аргумента, как и `xrange`.
Функция должна быть реализована как генератор, избегать любых ленивых итерируемых типов возврата, таких как списки, кортежи, наборы ... .

Примеры генераторов:
`g = arange (100000000000000)`
`g = arange(30L, 2)`
`g = arange(8, 2, -3L)`
`g = arange(9, 999, 7)`
и т.д.

Основное требование состоит в том, что функция не должна зависать или застревать в бесконечном цикле в любом случае.
По крайней мере, должно выводиться предупреждение о том, что такой случай не разрешен / не поддерживается.
Если это так, было бы неплохо перечислить сценарии, которые еще не поддерживаются или не реализованы.

```
def arange(*args, **kwargs):
    if 0 >= (len(args) + len(kwargs)) > 3:
        raise ValueError('arange requires 1-3 integer arguments')
    elif (len(args) + len(kwargs)) == 1:
        if len(kwargs) == 0:
            if args[0] == 0:
                return
            elif args[0] > 0:
                current, stop, step = 0, args[0], 1
            else:
                current, stop, step = 0, args[0], -1
        else:
            if kwargs["stop"] == 0:
                return
            elif kwargs["stop"] > 0:
                current, stop, step = 0, kwargs["stop"], 1
            elif kwargs["stop"] < 0:
                current, stop, step = 0, kwargs["stop"], -1
            else:
                raise ValueError('Your dict kwarg must have "stop" key for generator to be engaged')
    elif (len(args) + len(kwargs)) == 2:
        if len(args) == 2:
            if args[1] > args[0]:
                current, stop, step = args[0], args[1], 1
            elif args[1] < args[0]:
                current, stop, step = args[0], args[1], -1
            else:
                raise ValueError('Input an existing range for generator')
        elif len(kwargs) == 1:
            if kwargs["stop"] > args[0]:
                current, stop, step = args[0], kwargs["stop"], 1
            elif kwargs["stop"] < args[0]:
                current, stop, step = args[0], kwargs["stop"], -1
            else:
                raise ValueError('Use keyword "stop" for your end-range argument')
        elif len(kwargs) == 2:
            if kwargs["stop"] > kwargs["start"]:
                current, stop, step = kwargs["start"], kwargs["stop"], 1
            elif kwargs["stop"] < kwargs["start"]:
                current, stop, step = kwargs["start"], kwargs["stop"], -1
            else:
                raise ValueError('Set an existing range: use keywords start", "stop"')
    elif (len(args) + len(kwargs)) == 3:
        if len(args) == 3:
            if (args[1] > args[0] and args[2] > 0) or (args[1] < args[0] and args[2] < 0):
                current, stop, step = args[0], args[1], args[2]
            else:
                raise ValueError('Input the existing range for generator')
        if len(kwargs) == 3:
            if (kwargs["stop"] > kwargs["start"] and kwargs["step"] > 0) or (kwargs["stop"] < kwargs["start"] and kwargs["step"] < 0):
                current, stop, step = kwargs["start"], kwargs["stop"],  kwargs["step"]
            else:
                raise ValueError('Set an existing range: use keywords "start", "stop", "step" for your dict arguments')
        if len(kwargs) == 2:
            if (kwargs["stop"] > args[0] and kwargs["step"] > 0) or (kwargs["stop"] < args[0] and kwargs["step"] < 0):
                current, stop, step, = args[0], kwargs["stop"], kwargs["step"]
            else:
                raise ValueError('Set an existing range use keywords "stop", "step" for your dict arguments')
        if len(kwargs) == 1:
            if (args[1] > args[0] and kwargs["step"] > 0) or (args[1] < args[0] and kwargs["step"] < 0):
                current, stop, step = args[0], args[1], kwargs["step"]
            else:
                raise ValueError('Set an existing range: use keyword "step" for your dict argument')

    # Generating part of the function

    if step > 0:
        while current < stop:
            yield current
            current += step
    else:
        while current > stop:
            yield current
            current += step


#g = arange(100000000000000)
#g = arange(30L, 2)
#g = arange(20, 2, -3L)
#g = arange(9, 999, 7)
#g = arange(896, 8, **{'step': -101})
#g = arange(**{'stop': -40, 'start': 50, "step": -12})
#g = arange(-78, **{"stop": 94, "step": -13})
g = arange(0)

print (list(g))
print(g)
print (type(g))
```

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо за редактирование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял задачу:

```
def arange(start=None, stop=None, step=None):
    if start is None and stop is None:
        raise ValueError('either [start] or [stop] must be set to non-None value')
    if step == 0:
        raise ValueError('parameter [step] must be either positive or negative')
    if stop is None and start is not None:
        # passed a single parameter arange(stop)...
        stop, start = start, 0
    step = 1 if step is None else step
    start = 0 if start is None else start
    #if stop is None:
    #    raise ValueError('parameter [stop] must be set to non-None value')
    while (start < stop) if step > 0 else (start > stop):
        yield start
        start += step
```

PS по-моему ваша функция делает слишком много ненужных проверок, например если запустить в Python 2.x: `list(xrange(8, 2))` то получим пустой список, а ваша реализация вернет `[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]`. В условии об этом ничего не сказано...

Comment: да точно не заметил, должна работать как xrange, должен быть пустой список. Спасибо.